# How to list contents my present directory but only show the absolute file path and name?

Tags: linux, fedora, find, pwd

I have an alias:

```
alias lp=find $(pwd)
```

I would like this to be similar to ls and ll (list path) but this command searches through every directory instead of my present working directory.
I would mostly pipe this with grep but for now, I just want to get the command to display what I want.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that `lp` is also a command on many systems for printing.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you!  I can always change the alias 

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-maxdepth 1` option to prevent it going further down the tree.

```
find $(pwd) -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: Add `-mindepth 1` to exclude current directory. (And optionally use `$PWD` if shell expands this ...)